# Problem to get content from html string variable in php

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have this code:

```
     $doc = new \DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($content);


    $links = [];
  $container = $doc->getElementById("content");
  $arr = $container->getElementsByTagName("a");
  foreach($arr as $item) {
    $href =  $item->getAttribute("href");
    $title =  $item->getAttribute("title");
    $links[] = [
      'href' => $href,
      'title' => $title
    ];
  }
  for($i = 0, $l = count($links); $i < $l; ++$i) {
  echo $links[$i]['title'].' '.$links[$i]['href'].'<br />';
}
```

The html structure is like that:

```
<div class="post-content right-col">
                    <a title="" href="https://www.swisscars.pl/samochody/516321/">
                        <img src="https://swisscars.pl/uploads2/180843_0.jpg" alt="" class="thumb alignleft" height="75" width="75"/>
                    </a>
                    <h2 style="line-height:150%;">
                        <a href="https://www.swisscars.pl/samochody/516321/" rel="bookmark"  title="Renault Kangoo II (96&#8217;011 km)">
                            Renault Kangoo II (96&#8217;011 km)                     </a>
                    </h2>
                Do końca aukcji: <span id="countdown100">2018-10-23 14:00:00 GMT+02:00</span><p>DATA ZAKONCZENIA AUKCJI: 2018-10-23 14:00</p>

                </div>

            </div>
```

I want to get only values from a tag witch attribute rel="bookmark". Please help me with this. I try to use hasAttribute function but is not working. Please describe me what I can get only content from a tag with rel="bookmark" attribute. PHP have hasAttribute() function or something like this function?

Thanks for help

Comment: I can't find any element has `content` id in shown html

Comment: Use `if ($item->hasAttribute('rel') && $item->getAttribute('rel') == 'bookmark')..` in your loop

Answer (score 0):

XPath might be an option, you could do this:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query('//a[@rel="bookmark"]');
```

That should return a DOMNodeList you could loop through.